# How to download multiple images through an unique php file?

Tags: php, image

I need a php file with the ability to download multiple images per se from a folder on my server, with an unique ID per image.

e.g.

I have an image on my server: /home/example/public_html/multipleimage/2.png

And I want to download that image through the unique php file: http://example.com/file.php

I would type the following url: http://example.com/file.php?id=2
And the browser would have to return the image.

But... how should be the php file?
Can it be done without going through a database?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by download? Do you want the user to download the image? Or the server?

Comment: The server to download the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
readfile(
    sprintf(
        '/home/example/public_html/multipleimage/%d.png', 
        $_GET['id']
    )
);
```

See the following entries in the PHP Manual:

- [`header` - Send a raw HTTP header](http://php.net/header)
- [`readfile` - Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.](http://php.net/readfile)
- [`sprintf` - Returns a string produced according to the formatting string format.](http://php.net/sprintf)
- [`$_GET` - associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Note that I am using `sprintf` with `%d`, so it will silently convert any non-numeric id value to 0, so a malicious input like `../../etc/passwd` will try to read `0.png`. If you want to use anything else but numbers, you need to sanitize the input to prevent [directory traversal attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) and [null byte poisoning (before PHP 5.3.4)](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/2010/q4/202):

- [`filter_input` - Gets a specific external variable by name and optionally filters it](http://php.net/filter_input)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I know what you want but here it goes:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    echo file_get_contents("/home/example/public_html/multipleimage/".$_GET['id'].".png");
}

?>
```